# Operator Overloading In Python Not Able To Understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

My code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.x}i+{self.y}j"``

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

p1=Point(1,2)
print(p1)
p2=Point(3,4)
print(p2)

print(p1+p2)
print(type(p1+p2))
```

Result

```
1i+2j
3i+4j
4i+6j
<class '__main__.Point'>
```

I am not able to understand how this code is working.
Someone please explain it to me in simple language.

Answer (score 1):

Highly simplified.

When python sees x + y, it looks to see if `x` is an object that implements `__add__`.  Failing that, it sees if y is an object that implements `__radd__`.  Failing both of these, it does the normal operation.

In your code, `x` has a `__add__` method, so `x+y` is interpreted as `x.__add__(y)`.

Comment: +1. Similarly, python calls `str()` on the arguments passed to print. Which invokes `x.__str__()` if defined.